# Appending Arabic Text from AJAX XML Response Freezes Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, utf-8, arabic

I am working with a legacy site that grabs some XML content via AJAX, constructs a block of HTML code with it, and then appends it to a blank div. The XML makes heavy use of Arabic text.

It seems to work fine in all browsers except Chrome. In Chrome, page loading will die at the point of appending the string to the div. When I remove the Arabic text from the XML, the page loads just fine.

The HTML being generated has the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and the XML has this encoding tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Here is a sample of the XML that is being passed:

```
<segment>
    <content>السَّلامُ‮ ‬عَلَيْكُم‮.‬</content>
    <linked>true</linked>
    <glossWord>السَّلامُ‮ ‬عَلَيْكُم</glossWord>
    <glossTrans>Hello.  (Literally "Peace be upon you").</glossTrans>
    <glossExpl>This is a very commonly used greeting.  It works for any time of the the day.  It can also be used to mean 'goodbye'.</glossExpl>
</segment>
```

Interesting tidbit, when I went to create this question in Chrome, pasting the above into the form ALSO broke Chrome, and the browser froze solid. I had to reopen and submit it in Firefox. If this is a bug in Chrome it would be nice to be able to find a way to work around it, as I don't really like the idea of telling people, "Don't use X browser" to access a site.

Comment: Apparently accessing this page via Chrome (OSX 10.6.8) also results in a frozen page that has to be killed. Windows 7 Chrome works ok though, with both this and the original site I was working on. Some characters are showing up as boxes on Windows 7 Chrome, but the page is otherwise fine.

Comment: Even stranger, I just tried Chrome on another Mac running 10.8 and it also renders the page fine. So there's something up with my specific setup. I've disabled all extensions and still have the freezing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue, and it turned out to be Google Translate in Chrome on 10.6.8 having issues when I used multiple languages/characters.  I got around this by adding the class "notranslate" onto html elements that I didn't want Google Translate to bomb out on.

To quickly see if this works for you, add the class "notranslate" to your body and see if the page stops hanging. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Yup. That seems to have done it. I actually had set "notranslate" for other reasons, and now that I try it on the original machine, the problem is gone. I wonder if this is a Google issue or an Apple issue.